# XML design not showing in fullscreen - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

Here in above screen shot it just looking fine and full screen only on my Eclips(Graphic Layout), but when i run it on my real device , then it show padding from top Right and Left as below screenshot. i just want it should same display on my real device as display above in (Graphic layout)

[image]

Above is a screenshot. Below is my xml code. You can see in screenshot that the xml design is not showing as fullscreen. I want to show fullscreen all my items What am I missing?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:weightSum="4"
tools:context="selection.detail.Selection_datail_adapter" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#B2B2B2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bettypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_bettype"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_betTypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailCourseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_course"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_courseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailtimeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_time"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_timeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_stackID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!--  android:autoLink="web"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailurlID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Best Odds Available At"
            android:textColor="#0733F5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_horse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_horseID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_total_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_odds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_fractionID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_proofinglink_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_decimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_decimalID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post the code where you create the activity please. Are you using fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing padding/margins in one of the containers: ListView/RecyclerView, fragment layout, activity layout,please remove padding from listviews layout

Answer (score 1):

I am not into providing the exact codes, but your xml layout needs to be modified a lot. Too much nesting of `LinearLayout`s (do avoid that next time). I think you also missed putting the actual `TextView`s. But I think if you modify the xml below, you'll get your desired behavior.

Here's the xml (I modified it from the one you posted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B2B2B2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bettypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Bet Type"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_betTypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Each Way"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B2B2B2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailCourseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Detail Course"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_courseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="NEW CASTLE (A.W)"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B2B2B2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailtimeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Detail Time"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_timeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="16:15"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_stackID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B2B2B2"
        android:text="E/W Stake of 0.5pt(s) for a Total Stake of 1.00pts"
        android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    <!--  android:autoLink="web"-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detailurlID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#B2B2B2"
        android:text="Best Odds Available At William Hill"
        android:textColor="#0733F5" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_name_tipsterID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Horse" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_horseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Nakeeta" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_total_tipsterID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Odds Fraction" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_fractionID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="9/1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_proofinglink_tipsterID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Odds Decimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_decimalID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="10.00" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Cheers!

Comment: not help full, it is making design wrong as my requirement

Comment: my design layout is fine but i want no padding.top,right and just i want that, and here i am not giving padding, i dont know then why show not full @int j

Comment: Can you make at the very least a design on what you are aiming for? With paint? Because it's hard to picture what you're saying.

Comment: it just looking fine and full screen only on my Eclips(Graphic Layout), but when i run it on my real device , then it show padding from top ,right and left as same as i posted screenshot above

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. I'll try it again later and ket you know if somethings come up.

Answer (score 0):

here is your answer

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:weightSum="4"
tools:context="selection.detail.Selection_datail_adapter" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#B2B2B2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bettypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_bettype"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_betTypeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailCourseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_course"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_courseID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailtimeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/str_detail_time"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_timeID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detail_stackID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFFDFE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!--  android:autoLink="web"-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detailurlID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Best Odds Available At"
            android:textColor="#0733F5" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_horse" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_horseID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_total_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_odds" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_fractionID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_proofinglink_tipsterID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/str_detail_decimal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detail_decimalID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This layout just show fine in Graphic layout of eclips, but when i run on real device then it become change same as i posted above @Uma Achanta

Comment: please anyone help me :)